# How can taking Print Screen with VBA?

Tags: vba, printscreen

(I)

I need prepare print screen, with VBA. Are there any `function` for do that?

I tried record macro in MS-Word and MS-Excel, but nothing recorded when pressing `Print Screen` key.

Only `.Paste` method was recorded.

(II)

How can Print Screen minimized window? (since Windows task-bar can create a preview of a window even if it is minimized? [Effecting this question for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517512/how-can-i-print-screen-minimized-windows)) , by VBA

(III)

How can I assign above copied picture by `PrtSc` that was stored in clipboard, to `Picture` property of `Image` control in `User-form`?

Comment: You would have to use Wordbasic or API calls as explained here: http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/PrtSc.htm

Comment: Thank you for helpful reference. I will extend my question as above.

Comment: Actually the accepted answer for the question you added a link to isn't exclusively targeted towards C# *or any other language*. It's only talking about the concept. If the last captured image *before minimizing* is good enough for you, you could use the approach mentioned in that answer (with the help of the article provided by braX). If not, I also don't think it's possible to take a real time screenshot of a minimized window *while it's minimized*.

Comment: My question extended too, as above. (III)

Comment: Ahmed Abdelhameed- Are you know: How can showing numbers in a Lable on User-Form, with Persian (Arabic) digits? (I asked this question (Here) because of your name, as I had this question from last)

Comment: I extended my question as above. (Part III)